# TimeZoneInfo vs. Olson database

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

Do TimeZoneInfo and Olson database use identical identificators for time zones?

I get timezone id from GeoNames service (which is based on Olson database) and want to retrieve day light saving information for that timezone.

Comment: See also [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unicode consortium keeps a mapping between Olson database and Windows TimeZone Ids, which can be accessed [here](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/zone_tzid.html).

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-do-and-donts) SO question and answers for more daylight savings info (Daylight saving time - do and don’ts).

Answer (score 3):

No they don't use the same identifiers. A possible solution is to use [Noda-Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) which foregoes TimeZoneInfo in favour of Olson timezones.

Further reading: [What's wrong with DateTime anyway?](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)